# clearfix / JavaScript, absolute position, changeable height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so I have relative div, and inside it I have two absolute divs, rights and left. Under relative div I want sticky footer, or something like that, but relative div has not children's height, because children is absolute. I know that, I should use javaScript (because of absolute divs it's impossible with css, clearfix), but what is the best way to keep parent's height like children using JavaScript? I do not prefer to set div's height permanently, because it could be uncomfortable with future content changes.

Maybe someone has some ids how to set parent's height like children's without setting height permanently and  when it's impossible to use clearfix trick?

I will be really grateful for every suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the height of your parent container using .outerHeight() or .height(). Then you can use the .on() function to fire the SetHeight function on  screen resize and load.

```
function SetHeight(div){

    var x = $(div).outerHeight();
    // to get the height

    $(div).children().css('height', x); 
    // set the childrens height
}

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    // fire the function
    SetHeight('#my_div');
});
```

Comment: I accept your answer. It's really simple and good idea just to write function that to do it. Thanks.